# What font does Ubuntu 20.04 use for creating keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, fonts, unicode

In Ubuntu 20.04, I have created a new input method for my language (Hmong, language code: hmn) by
editing the text file template.txt in the directory
/usr/share/ibus-table/tables.

After installing the keyboard here is what it shows up: [keyboard in setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7KMU.png).

I got the keyboard to work by testing it in LibreOffice, Gedit, and FireFox browser. Here is an image of my keyboard layout that I want to implement
[keyboard layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtuTD.png)
For example: I can type:   ?. So now I want to modify the "Show Keyboard Layout" option so that it also displays correctly for anyone who needs a visual image.

Right now the keyboard layout still shows the default English (US) [qwerty layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP2SF.png), even though the text shows up correctly. So my question is, what font (and in which directory) does Ubuntu used for creating the "Show Keyboard Layout" for a particular input method (or language)? (On Windows there are two programs that can modify the keyboard layout: Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator and Keyman Developer). Another example, if I switch to a thai keyboard, this is what it shows up [thai key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRaU8.png) and for a modify german [keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGOZl.png). Hopefully these examples make it clear.

If the font has nothing to do with it, then where is Ubuntu pulling the keyboard layout from?

Do I need to create a new language package for Ubuntu to recognize this new language?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if you can tell which font and language on what keyboard you want to use, then a lot of expert here can assist you, for example, NotoCJK and Japanese, I have some idea. But I can't answer the generic question. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` This does change to fit into your keyboard-layout

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand better. So you created an *input method*, which actually is an additional layer on top of some XKB keyboard layout.

The "Show Keyboard Layout" option only shows the underlying XKB layout. That's the intended behavior, and can't be changed easily.

I'm not aware of any equivalent to "Show Keyboard Layout" to visualize an input method. For many input methods, which need a series of key presses to get the desired character, that wouldn't make sense anyway.

And yes, fonts has nothing to do with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.
I created an onscreen keyboard layout for my language by customizing onboard.
Install onboard.
In onboard settings - layout - select the layout which you want to convert - then select  new - give name
Select  open layout folder - open the *.onboard file with text editor.

Bottom row is AA no need to edit this,  one above is AB , AB1 is z (ignore the < symbol if any before z). like this edit for rows AC & AD.
Tips :- edit only keys that need to be changed.
Below is 3 lines of my custom compact layout edit of onboard to show  Tamil99 keyboard

```
<key group="alphanumeric" id="AB06" label="n  ல" shift_label="N  ௐ"/> 
<key group="alphanumeric" id="AC08" label="k  ம" shift_label="K   ''"/>
<key group="alphanumeric" id="AC09" label="l   த" shift_label="L"/>
```

Font can be changed in onboard settings / preferences - theme - customize theme - labels.
Onboard can be used to type after changing keyboard layout to the desired language in top menu or by shortcut key